Issue with Pinia Store: Set object methods not accessible within actions due to Proxy
I'm using Pinia for state management in my Vue.js application, and I've encountered an issue where Set object methods are not accessible within actions. My state is defined as follows:
state: () => {
  return {
    user: null as User,
    abilities: new Set([] as string[]),
  }
},

In my actions, I have a method that checks if a user has a specific ability and also a method that is loading the abilities. However, when I try to use the has method of the Set object, it throws an error saying "has is not a function." Here's the action method:
allows(ability: string) {
  if (!this.user) {
    return false;
  }

  return this.abilities.has(ability);
},
    async getAbilities() {
      if (!this.user) {
        return
      }

      let abilities = [
        { code: 'indexSettings', allowed: true }
      ] // this is fetched from API this is just for reference
      
      await Promise.all(
        abilities.map(async (ability) => {
          if (ability.allowed) {
            this.abilities.add(ability.code)
          }
        })
      )
    },


From my observation, the abilities property seems proxied, preventing direct access to the Set methods. How can I access the Set methods in this context? Is there a specific way to handle Set objects in Pinia, or am I missing how I should structure my store?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . I don't see a problem that could be associated with it. This will happen only if you reassigned abilities

I've tried to expand on my example to better illustrate how I'm adding abilities to the state property

It looks ok, the problem is not reproducible, could be odd package versions or something that didn't show. Reactive sets work exactly as you expect. There is supposed to be this.abilities.has() with no oddities. Try to provide a demo, e.g. https://play.pinia.vuejs.org/ or stackblitz

we suddenly experience this,
we even lock the pinia version, it must be a pinia dependency.
